# YouTube Video popup when the user click on YouTube Video

Tags: wordpress, popup

I have embedded the youtube video on my website in Wordpress. But when the user clicks on the video it will show in a popup. Not able to do that. I have tried the popups plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below wordpress plugin for play the video in lightbox popup.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-video-lightbox/

Here you can see the simple installation steps to install in your theme.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-video-lightbox/#installation

Comment: I have used all these. Try to understand. I have embedded a youtube video using an iframe and it is showing youtube video but when the user clicks on that video it should open in a popup. It is not opening in the popup and it is paying there only. @Chetan Panchal

Comment: I Have used this plugin but auto_thumb image is so small. @Chetan Panchal

Comment: I want to open popup on the video itself. @Chetan Panchal

Comment: Have you user same as Short code mentioned in plugin ?

Comment: Yes @Chetan Panchal

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of Lightbox plugins serving the same business One of them which is easy to use as well is [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) plugin.

This plugin comes in all forms including wordpress plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-fancybox/

Try using this and make sure you configure it properly.

**********Updated Part**********

This is one of the way to implement it.
Below is the line of code required :

1.) adding the button for event triggering :

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/your_video_id?modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0" class="video_btn pull-right fancybox iframe"><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i> Watch Video</a>
```

2.)Configure the fancybox

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
            autoSize: false,
            autoDimensions: false,
            width: 630,
            height: 425,
            fitToView: false,
            padding: 0,
            title: this.title,
            href: $(this).attr('href'),
            type: 'iframe'

    });
```

Comment: I have used all these. Try to understand. I have embedded a youtube video using an iframe and it is showing youtube video but when the user clicks on that video it should open in a popup. It is not opening in the popup and it is paying there only. @Faizunnabi

Comment: Bro , for the functionality that you want, you can add an external event which on click will trigger the popup and then you can play the video as you want.For eg. try adding a transparent div frame over the video iframe which on click will trigger the pop up or else add a overlay play button.

Comment: Can you Code it. @Faizunnabi

Comment: No bro . Suppose I added video like <div style="position:relative;height:0;padding-bottom:56.25%"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vbwLi_M0pm4?ecver=2" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div> . It displays as a video but when the user click on that video it should open in open. @Faizunnabi. In your code it is displaying as a text.